# powershell seemingly forgets ntfssecurity module after a script finishes

Tags: powershell, module

the module is at http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85

when i run a script which uses the get-ace cmdlet in a Windows Powershell enviroment and finishes, exit it using ctrl-c or using exit command in the script, i have to restart my Powershell environment to use my script again. Otherwise i end up getting errors that it doesn't know what get-ace is. yet during the whole time the script runs for the first time, it can run for days and finish fine.

any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: its probably (repeatedly) doing an "Import-Module". When Powershell does "Import-Module" more than once on the same module, it gets funny.

Comment: i can do import module more then once in a powershell session and it seems fine, i run my script which does the import, works fine the first time, then won't ever again till i restart the session. i just discovered something, if i import the module prior to running a script, the script can keep adding the module all it likes, the rest of the script continues to work fine in that powershell session. If i let the script load the module for the first time, then importing it outside the script or in the script, it will no longer work properly.

Comment: because its probably still lingering around in your session.

Comment: in what way?
how do un-linger it?
as i said i import the module before the script and everything runs smoothly, i import the module via the script it only runs once smoothly and never again, even if i remove the import statement in the script for 2nd + runs of the script.

Comment: just taking another look at the options for import-module.
i found if i just call import-module -name [module name] -force, the -force argument seems to at least allow the script to be run more then once, though when i run the command with -force outside the script, it will work without having to enter the import-module command again. perhaps it's something do to with scope in which the module is imported into?

Comment: When you "import the module", you are being redundant. Your session already (apparently) has the module loaded. Reloading of modules can produce strange behaviour, as I have witnessed with my own scripts. You only need to load the module ONCE per session. My guess is you are re-using your session, therefore, reloading your module redundantly.